# Как определить какой элемент выбран из списка на панели задач?

Tags: c#, wpf

Такая проблема: Я создаю список, который вызывается нажатием ПКМ по панели задач. Там есть три кнопки что можно сделать, в данном случае это действия с браузером. Дело все в том что мне нужно понять какой элемент из списка выбрал пользователь. Список выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто подсказать как определить какой элемент выбран.
Вот код создания списка, может где то здесь это есть.

```
JumpList jumpList = JumpList.CreateJumpList();

            JumpListCustomCategory category = new JumpListCustomCategory(rm.GetString("expressPanel", new CultureInfo(languagePacks)));

            Calling_a_private_window(privat);
            category.AddJumpListItems(
                new JumpListLink(w, rm.GetString("newWindow", new CultureInfo(languagePacks))) { Arguments = url },
                new JumpListLink(w, rm.GetString("private", new CultureInfo(languagePacks))) { Arguments = privat + url },
                new JumpListLink(w, rm.GetString("open", new CultureInfo(languagePacks))) { Arguments = url });

            jumpList.AddCustomCategories(category);
            jumpList.Refresh();
            Close();
```

Может кто  подсказать с данной проблемой?

Comment: [Документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.jumplist?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) читали? Вообще для кликабельных элементов есть 3 основных способа - команда `ICommand`, событие `Click` и `SelectedItem` для контролов коллекций типа `ListBox`.

Comment: А вообще эта менюшка - самая бесполезная фича в винде, я за всю жизнь максимум пару раз туда ткнул, и то один раз из этих двух - мисклик. Когда он появился в семёре, первое, что я выучил, это то что надо зажать Shift, чтобы открыть нормальное контекстное меню. Не тратьте на него много сил.

Comment: @aepot вот не надо, это наиболее полезное меню. Каждый день пользуюсь им многократно. Я почти перестал пользоваться главным меню, стартовым экраном и рабочим столом как распробовал ту фичу.

Comment: Мнэ-э... Я вбил в поиск "c# JumpListLink", первая же ссылка содержит ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35179434/5045688. / Я вам уже писал что-то ранее, видимо та тема удалена. Начнём по новой. Переменная `url` в вашем коде чему равна? Покажите. Заодно и `privat`. / Подумайте, что происходит при нажатии на пункт JumpList, когда приложение ещё не запущено?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я уже решил свою проблему. Но не так как в ссылке. Поэтому спасибо за совет. В следующий раз рассмотрю и его.

Comment: @aepot функция полезная, но очень мало по ней документации. Плюс библиотеки уже убраны с главной System.

Comment: _уже решил_ - ну так опубликуйте ответ.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ааа так можно, тогда ок